# Does iterating of a tree map's values and removing them via this iterator modify the treemap?

Tags: java, collections

Let's say I have a TreeMap like this:

```
TreeMap<K, V> map = ...
map.put(key, val)
```

I then do the following:

```
Iterator<K> iter = map.values().iterator();
while(iter.hasNext()) {
    iter.next();
    iter.remove();
}
```

After this code executes, will `map.get(key)` be `null` or will it equal `val`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just try it..

But yes, removing a value trough an iterator will affect the original collection. It wouldn't be much use otherwise, would it?

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#values%28%29):

> Returns a Collection view of the values contained in this map. The collection's iterator returns the values in ascending order of the corresponding keys. The collection is backed by the map, so changes to the map are reflected in the collection, and vice-versa. If the map is modified while an iteration over the collection is in progress (except through the iterator's own remove operation), the results of the iteration are undefined.
>
> The collection supports element removal, which removes the corresponding mapping from the map, via the Iterator.remove, Collection.remove, removeAll, retainAll and clear operations. It does not support the add or addAll operations.